# Application function match two variables getting run time error

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Set rng1 = Sheets("Reference").Range("a2:a2000")
  Set rng2 = Sheets("Reference").Range("b2:b2000")

      var1 = ActiveSheet.Range("c2").Value
      var2 = c.Offset(0, -1).Value


 c.Value = Application.Match(criteria1 & criteria2, rng1 & rng2, 0)
```

I am trying to match two variables from one sheet to another to see if the value exists with both criteria in the reference worksheet, but I keep getting a type mismatch error. Match line is the only line I am getting an error in.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx says the first argument to Application.match is a value, not a criterion?

Comment: Your question needs a bit of work sorry. If you are asking about a type mismatch error you should show the types that you have defined your variables as. Right now we cant see how criteria1 or criteria2 are declared or set, we see var1 and var2 but they're not used, we don't know what c is either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a multi-column MATCH lookup in VBA like that.

Best you could do is create a valid formula and the `Evaluate` method:

(untested)

```
Dim f As String, rng1, rng2, var1, var2, c As Range

Set c = Range("B6")

Set rng1 = Sheets("Reference").Range("a2:a2000")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Reference").Range("b2:b2000")

var1 = ActiveSheet.Range("c2").Value
var2 = c.Offset(0, -1).Value

f = "MATCH(""" & var1 & """&""" & var2 & """," & _
     rng1.Address() & "&" & rng2.Address() & ", 0)"

c.Value = rng1.Worksheet.Evaluate(f)
```

For anyone unfamiliar with this use of MATCH:
https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/

Comment: Thanks Tim that worked. I will have to read more about the evaluate function.